# Couldn't find Module in aws cfn registry after registering module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I couldn't find the module in Cloudformation registry under Activated Extensions->Modules(Privately registered) section.
This is the command I ran for registering the module

```
aws cloudformation register-type --type-name VS::S3::Bucket::MODULE --schema-handler-package s3://test-modules-template/s3-modules-template.zip --type MODULE --profile xxx
```

and got the registration token successfully.

But it is not showing up in the aws console mentioned at the top section? Any help is appreciated..

Thanks,
Devops-guy